# About template class grammar

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, parameter-pack

I want to ask something about the template class. I know the basics like:

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
class tmp{
...
}
```

However, in the starter file of my programming assignment, I saw a new format as:

```
template<typename X, typename... Y>
class tmp<std::tuple<Y...>,X>{
...
}
```

Here, I know "..." is the parameter pack, but why there is another "< >" after the name of the class??

Comment: Specialization.

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
template<typename X, typename... Y>
class tmp<std::tuple<Y...>,X>{
...
}
```

is a notation to say:

*We have a template with parameter `X` and a parameter pack `Y`. The class `tmp` is a template class that use the parameter pack `Y` in a `tuple` variable, and `X` as a simple template variable.*

However this is a **specialization** of the template.